# Javascript on ajax keeps growing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, three.js

I have a site with a configurable 3d object which has some properties and as i change those properties I reload the div with 3d object to reflect new properties. It works fine except that the script data keeps adding on. Not only the script slows down after 30 reloads, but here is what happens. I added rotation object rotation to rendering function and with every reload the button keeps spinning faster! After 5 reloads it spins like crazy. The spinning function is simple:

```
    function animate() {
    if (typeof(objektas) !== 'undefined') {
        rotation++;
        if (rotation >= 360) rotation = 0;
        objektas.rotation.y = rotation * Math.PI * 2 / 360;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate, renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

My guess is that with every load render those animate functions are stacked and for example in second reload they are called twice instead of once. Can somebody explain how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't fully understand, but it *sounds* like you're attaching an event handler in an event handler. Either attach it once at the start of your script, or remove the existing event handlers and attach the new one if there is something more specific about the new event handler. Sorry I can't be more specific to your context, I'm not sure what `requestAnimationFrame` or `render` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `animate` is first invoked, it will continuously re-invoke itself. You're using recursion to create a continuous loop.

My understanding is that every time you reload, you reinvoke the `animate` function. If you invoke it a second time, you will have two continuous `animate` loops happening, interweaved on the same UI thread. Your `rotation` variable will be incrementing twice as fast.

Call it a third time, you now have three `animate` loops. Call it 30 times, then the 30 interweaved loops are going to cause serious performance issues.

The solution: at the place where you first call it, make sure it only gets called once.

Have a global variable:

```
var hasCalledAnimate = false;
```

And at the place where you first invoke it:

```
if(!hasCalledAnimate) {
   hasCalledAnimate = true;
   animate();
}
```

If you want to be absolutely 100% sure nobody could ever call it a second time, use closures.

```
   var animate = (function () {
       function _animate() {
           if (typeof (objektas) !== 'undefined') {
               rotation++;
               if (rotation >= 360) rotation = 0;
               objektas.rotation.y = rotation * Math.PI * 2 / 360;
           }
           requestAnimationFrame(_animate, renderer.domElement);
           renderer.render(scene, camera);
       }
       var _hasInvoked = false;
       return function () {
           if (!_hasInvoked) {
               _hasInvoked = true;
               _animate();
           }
       }
   })();
```

Now `animate` will be truly idempotent - you can call it as many times as you like but you know the loop will only be started once.